# Select 1 single random result from Foreach

Tags: php

I have the code below, which is working perfectly for returning all of the files from our `$base` location. However, I am wondering how we can select only one random result from this and display it on the page.

There's 44 total results for it to shuffle from, and I want it to display a random account each time a user views the page.

```
$red = file_get_contents($base);
$matches = explode(PHP_EOL, $red);
foreach ($matches as $match){
    $match_explode_1 = explode(' password:', $match);
    $match_explode_2 = explode(' username:', $match_explode_1[0]);
    $data['email_addresss'] = str_replace('email:', '', $match_explode_2[0]);
    $data['username'] = $match_explode_2[1];
    $data['password'] = base64_encode($match_explode_1[1]);

    print '<pre>';
    print_r($data); 
    print '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities for selecting a single random value from an array. You can use [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomise the array, and then take the first element. Or you can use [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to pick a random key in the array. For example:

```
shuffle($matches);
$match = $matches[0];
```

or

```
$match = $matches[array_rand($matches)];
```

Comment: This doesn't show OP how to use the code you've sent him at all

Comment: @Someone OP has an array called `$matches` that he wants to select one random value from. He already has the code to display the values from it. I don't understand your comment and downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$random=shuffle($matches) ?:  array_rand($matches,1);
$firstRandom=$random[0]:
```

?: is operetaror shortly if operator